# jQuery:Something fishy about my URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

The following URI works in my browser (getting back the intended xml file):

```
http://ipaddress:port/server/gate?Command=GET%26info
```

But when I write the following to work with jQuery, it doesn't. The response is 200 OK but I get a blank XML file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://ipaddress:port/server/gate?Command=GET%26info",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parseXml
          });
    });
```

I tried replacing the `%26` with `&` but that doesn't work either. Is there something I am fundamentally doing wrong?

Comment: Is the HTML page the code is contained running on the same server? You cannot access another URL from Ajax calls due to the same origin policy. If it is on the same server, use `url: "/server/gate?Command=GET%26info",`

Comment: Is your code and the other page you are trying to get in same domain? Cross domain will work in browser but not through ajax

Comment: My bad! Yes. They are on a different server. Thanks for the clarification.... Almost forgot about it for a second.

Comment: Voting to close since it's already been answered.

Comment: @Bears will eat you - I don't think that's how it works

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server that serves the xml, you can now in FF3.5 and IE8 and more use [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) - cross origin resource sharing. It works like magic

Example here in my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290068/please-help-test-a-cors-issue-in-firefox-jquery-ajax-when-401) which has not yet been answered