# Chrome extension jquery Ajax preflight OPTIONS

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, cors, preflight

I need to access an API backend of a web app from a Chrome extension. The xhr requests that originate from the webpage itself are always preflighted (OPTIONS). However, I can not get the extension to fire preflight requests, it fires the GET requests and the servers authorization mechanism rejects calls without the OPTIONS first.

I read what is available on stackoverflow and tried to add a random "x-weird-header" in an attempt to send a preflight first but it didn't work.

Another thing I can't understand is, Chrome sends an "Origin" header for calls from the webpage but the request from my extension is missing the "Origin" header.

How can I get OPTIONS sent first? and why is the "Origin" missing in my request?

Thanks!

```js
 $.ajax({
   url : url, /* url is https and it is called from a non ssl but same domain origin*/
     type : 'GET',
     beforeSend : function( xhr ) {
         xhr.setRequestHeader( "Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*");
         xhr.setRequestHeader( "Authorization", "BEARER " + auth_token );
         xhr.setRequestHeader( "x-weird-header", "utf8" );
     },
     success : function (data) {
       console.log(data);
     },
     error : function (data, errorThrown) {
       console.log(data);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think reading on [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) might help you with this. Your chrome extension is making requests to a remote server therefore you need cross-origin permissions. With regard to your OPTIONS problem, try using this OPTIONS as mentioned in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023454/jquery-ajax-fails-to-work-options-pre-flight-request-made-when-headers-are-spe):

> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With,
>   Session