# “SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.” in IE11 with fetch API

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cors, internet-explorer-11, fetch-api

I'm calling an external POST request from localhost with JavaScript's fetch function.

Everything is working fine with all the browsers except for IE11, which is returning this error on the request:

`“SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.” in IE`

This is the code:

```
export const signIn = (email, password) => {
  const base64 = btoa(`${email}:${password}`);
  const headers = new Headers({
    Authorization: `Basic ${base64}`
  });
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(`${__API__}/spa/token`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers,
      credentials: "include"
    })
      .then(resp => {
        if (resp.status >= 400) {
          reject(resp);
        }
        resolve(resp);
      })
      .catch(reject);
  });
};
```

One of the "solutions" that I've read it this other thread ([How to solve the error "SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied." in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903550/how-to-solve-the-error-script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x80070005-ac)) was to change IE's configuration here:

Internet Options> Security > ENABLE The Following setting: Miscellaneous > Access data sources across domains.

For me, that's not a solution because I'll won't request the final user to change his/her configuration.

Also, when I'm inspecting the request in IE, I can see that the POST is actually being called as a GET.

*UPDATE*: If I remove the headers option it works, but I need the headers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve the error "SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied." in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903550/how-to-solve-the-error-script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x80070005-ac)

Comment: So how are you making the Ajax request? Are you setting the CORS headers? Are you running as IE11 or in compat mode?

Comment: @epascarello I'll update the question

Comment: Not a duplicate, @31piy. Just edited.

Comment: The GET you are seeing is probably the options preflight request....

Comment: If you set the mode does it make a difference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters

Comment: @epascarello just tried all options with mode. Same result :(

Comment: @epascarello indeed it looks like the 200 GET is IE11's mode of preflight

Comment: If I remove the headers from the request, it works. But I need the headers :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023454/jquery-ajax-fails-to-work-options-pre-flight-request-made-when-headers-are-spe

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this was the solution for me:

I discovered that the issue was to send the fetch with headers. If first I send it without the headers (like a preflight request) and then send it normally it just works.

Of course, this is just for IE.

Comment: This answer solved it for me. Did you ever find a better solution to this though?